# Octave won't exort LaTex symbols

Tags: export, latex, octave

I'm having a problem where Octave will render figures just fine in the figure box, but then refuses to properly export to PNG when I use the print() command.  This is also true when I try other formats like EPS or JPG.

My current version of Octave is 3.8.1-1ubuntu1, which is up to date at the time of this post.  My Ubuntu version is also 14.04.  I do not receive any error messages when the code runs.

The script commands used to plot are pretty basic.  For example:

```
linewidth = 4;
xStr = 'Particle Diameter (\mum)';
yStr = 'Scattering Cross-Section (\mum^2)';
FontName  = 'Times New Roman';
LabelFontSize = 22;
AxisFontSize  = 18;

F1 = figure(1);
clf('reset');
plot(diameter*1e6,sigma_0*1e12,'k','linewidth',linewidth);
hold on
plot(diameter*1e6,sigma_1*1e12,'r','linewidth',linewidth);
X = xlabel(xStr);
set(X,'FontName',FontName,'fontsize',LabelFontSize);
Y = ylabel(yStr);
set(Y,'FontName',FontName,'fontsize',LabelFontSize);
axis([xMin xMax sigMin sigMax]);
set(gca,'fontsize',AxisFontSize,'linewidth',2);
legend('2.0 \mum','3.8 \mum',4);

print(F1,'Mie.png','-dpng');
```

The strange thing is that I have other images from months ago that rendered the LaTex bits just fine, and even used nearly identical code.  That almost seems like some recent software upgrade may have killed my plotting.

I appreciate any help you can give me.  This issue is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem when using the OpenGL toolkits (graphics_toolkit FLTK) which is default in octave3.8.x. Previous versions used gnuplot for printing.

So you have two choices:

- Switch back to gnuplot with "graphics_toolkit gnuplot" before doing any plotting. You may also add this to your .octaverc so it's set every time you start octave
- Use LaTex output: http://wiki.octave.org/Printing_with_FLTK

Comment: Excellent!  I used the "graphics_toolkit gnuplot" command and that fixed everything.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I apologize.  I'm a little new to SE and didn't realize that was a thing I'm supposed to do.  It's done now.  Thank you again.   :P